# css, не происходит выравнивание по центру

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь выравнять ютуб-видео по центру моего контент-блока, но оно почему-то ни в какую не хочет. Почитал в интернете, что нужно обернуть в еще один `div`, но толку никакого. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка, может что-то не доглядел.

```css
html,
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #C4C4C4;
}


/* VIDEOS */

#videos {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #2C2C2C;
  box-shadow: -5px 4px 14px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
}

.video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.video-container iframe {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- VIDEO -->
  <section id="videos">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="video-container">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CY8kRr-ECPM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вашему блоку видео задать `text-align: center`

```
   #videos .video {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```